# Printing something in stack (assembly)

Tags: assembly, memory, nasm, x86-64, system-calls

In linux you can print something using the system call number 4:

```
mov eax,4       ;system call number
mov ebx,0       ;file descriptor
mov ecx,msg     ;adress of message in data segment
mov edx,length  ;length of message
```

But, How do you print something from stack segment?

I tried this:

```
push 'H'
push 'e'
push 'l'
push 'l'
push 'o'
push ' '
push 'w'
push 'o'
push 'r'
push 'l'
push 'd'
mov eax,4       ;system call number
mov ebx,0       ;file descriptor
mov ecx,ebp     ;adress of message
mov edx,11      ;length of message
```

But doesn't print anything.

**EDIT:** I made some changes to my code and now it is so:

```
section .data
msg: db "Hola mundo",0Ah
ok: db "OK",0Ah

section .text
global _start
_start:
push 'leH'
push 'w ol'
push 'dlro'
mov eax,4       ;system call number
mov ebx,1       ;file descriptor
mov ecx,esp     ;adress of message in data segment
mov edx,11      ;length of message
mov eax,1
xor ebx,ebx     ;same as move ebx,0 but better
int 0x80
```

**EDIT 2** (still not working)

```
section .data
msg: db "Hello world",0Ah

section .text
global _start
_start:
push 'leH'
push 'w ol'
push 'dlro'
mov eax,4       ;system call number
mov ebx,1       ;file descriptor
mov ecx,esp     ;adress of message in data segment
mov edx,11      ;length of message
int 0x80
mov eax,1
xor ebx,ebx     ;same as move ebx,0 but better
int 0x80
```

Responding to the comment, I assemble and compile with:

```
nasm -f elf64 hello.asm && ld hello.o && ./a.out
```

I'm working in Ubuntu 64-bit Linux.

Comment: `ebp` is not the stack pointer, `esp` is. Also, `push` will use 4 bytes per character so that won't quite work.

Comment: Not to mention using `push` will reverse your string.

Comment: @Jester the reversing of the string is something I wanted to test

Comment: As Jester pointed out should be _ESP_ and _EBP_ and if you want to print that string out backwards the Pushes could be replaced with `push 'leH'`
`push 'w ol'`
`push 'dlro'` . As well EBX should be 1 not 0 for standard output. (0 is standard input)

Comment: I made the changes but the program still doesn't work

Comment: Your code doesn't include an `int 0x80` or `syscall` instruction.  Of course it doesn't print anything.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64, and use `strace` to see what args you're actually passing.  Also note that `0` is stdin, not stdout.

Comment: @PeterCordes I included the int 0x80 instruction. I only was showing a snippet code

Comment: Are you assembling this as a 64-bit program or 32-bit? This code won't run properly as 64-bit code because `int 0x80` emulation in 64-bit code can't handle 64--bit addresses which are required when using the stack. The stack addresses require the full 64-bit address in _RSP_. That can only be done if you use the 64-bit System V Linux system call interface via the `syscall` instruction. Infromation on using that can be found here in [Ryan Chapman's blog](http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/).

Comment: Your edited code is missing `int 0x80` **before** `mov eax,1` so that the output system call is done. Your code sets up a write system call but then does nothing and then sets up the exit system call and executes that with `int 0x80`

Comment: If you are assembling this with `-felf64` using _NASM_ this code won't work for the reason I gave above. Can you show us how you assemble and link this code to a final executable. I'd expect you'd see nothing and the program exit if you were in fact building this as a 64-bit executable.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I was assembling and linking (and executing) with `nasm -f elf64 hello.asm && ld hello.o && ./a.out` and I'm working in ubuntu linux 64 bit

Comment: @MichaelPetch Please post your comment as answer, I would like to accept it

Comment: near duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain (probably the latter since your stack pushes only work in 32-bit mode.)  But see the former for a `write` system call with a string on the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was originally lacking a key piece of information. You assemble and link with:

```
nasm -f elf64 hello.asm && ld hello.o && ./a.out
```

This generates a 64-bit executable. `int 0x80` shouldn't be used in 64-bit executables. In 64-bit programs that stack pointer can't be represented in just the 32-bit *ESP* register. The only way to use 64-bit pointers is to use the `syscall` instruction. [Ryan Chapman's blog](http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/) has good information on using the 64-bit system call interface via the `syscall` instruction.

If you modify your code to conform to that interface it could look something like:

```
section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov dword [rsp-4], `rld\n`
                    ; Use back ticks instead of single quotes
                    ; To parse the string like C. We can write safely
                    ; in the 128 bytes below RSP because of the
                    ; Linux red zone.
    mov dword [rsp-8], 'o Wo'
    mov dword [rsp-12],'Hell'
    mov eax,1       ;Write system call number
    mov edi,eax     ;file descriptor (1 = stdout)
    lea rsi,[rsp-12];address of message on the stack
    mov edx,12      ;length of message
    syscall
    mov eax,60      ;Exit system call
    xor edi,edi     ;RDI=0
    syscall
```

This code writes constants to 32-bit registers as they are zero extended to the entire 64-bit register. We can't push 64-bit immediate values, but we can write the string onto the stack directly as 32-bit DWORD values. We don't need to adjust *RSP* because Linux has a 128 byte [red zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(computing)) that is protected from being clobbered by asynchronous events and signals.

If you want to use *C* style strings with *C* escape characters in it, *NASM* [supports backtick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36708284/3857942) instead of single quote to make the distinction. This allows you to use something like `\n` as a character denoting the new line character. I mention this as it seems you wanted to place a newline character in some of the code that was posted in your question that has since been removed.

Comment: For code-density, you can actually mix `push` and `mov`, e.g. `push 'Hell'` / `mov dword [rsp+4], 'o Wo'`.  As a bonus, you end up with rsp pointing to the front of your string, so you only need a `mov` instead of `lea`.  Also an easy way to get a null-terminated string for `execve` without having a literal 0 byte in your machine code.  But +1 for a good non-`push` example which is much simpler to understand!

Comment: (actually for code-density you'd want `push imm32` to push the end of the string, then `mov reg, imm64` / `push reg` to push the next 8 bytes.  12 immediate bytes and 2 opcode + 1 prefix byte.  And you can `lea rsi, [rsp-8]` / syscall and restore RSP after push with a dummy `pop`.)